# MSC Nastran CQUAD8 on a pipe - excessive pivot ratio

Tags: buckling, nastran

I'm modelling a pipe in Patran with CQUAD8 elements, but I get this error, like the structure is not costrained. I do have costrains on both ends of the pipe. What can the problem be?

If I use automatic costrains it works, but I don't know why and where these constrains are put. I don't have any control over the solution. I'd like to know the actual problem here. With CQUAD4 works fine.

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: This is impossible to answer with no specific information on either the model or the error message. The only general advice is "don't use ***any*** Nastran elements with mid-side nodes, unless you are following a validated modeling procedure that has been proved to work correctly".

Comment: I don’t remember the error code, I need to check the f06 filez but it’s the classic too many pivot ratio error. The model is just a cylinder modelled with thin shell elements.

Comment: We need a lot more detail here. I'd suggest to post a link to your entire deck and f06 file.